# Full calendar ResourceView horizontal and vertical axis

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using the fullcalendar resourceviews fork version 1.6.1.6...
I used an older version which had the resources on the top and the times on the left axis.
But now it is different. The times are on the top and the resources are on the left axis. It's not that good anymore. Is there a way to change it?

I need the newer version of it because of the refetchResources function.

Comment: Are you using **Ike Lin fullCalendar** (horizontal resourceView)  http://www.ikelin.com/jquery-fullcalendar-resource-day-view/ ? If not, which one you using?

Comment: Hi, yes that's the one i USED. But it doesn't support the refetchResources function. That's why I was looking for a new resourceview. I need it because the resources change from day to day... That means I do have other resources on mondays than on tuesdays and so on.

Comment: Did u checked Jarno kurlin fullCalendar has refetchResources but it supports vertical resourceView which u doesn't want?

Comment: Exactly. I downloaded Jarno Kurlin's fullCalendar. It does have the refetchResources... But the vertical resourceView is not good... :(

Comment: **Jarno Kurlin's** will support only *vertical resourceView*, as well I have mailed him last year regrading his support for *horizontal resourceView*, he says he doesn't have the plan for that. You can create a **issue** in **Ike Lin Github repo** and assign him, then he will be notified.

Comment: Have a look here and see whether it helps you. http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/index.shtml

Comment: Hmm I don't know but that link doesn't help in this case. All I want to do is to modify that resourceView so, that I can disable some timeslots - like using working hours for the different persons.

Comment: let me know is there a way to refetchResources from http://www.ikelin.com/jquery-fullcalendar-resource-day-view/.?

Comment: i tried all way to refetch resources and failed.. so let me know if anyone can help me in this situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the resource object (using Ike Lin fullCalendar) and added an array which includes the number of the day, start time and end time like 0 -> 09:00 -> 12:00, 1 10:00 -> 15:30 ...

Then I changed the fullcalendar.js

```
function updateCells() {
    var i;
    var headCell;
    var bodyCell;
    var date;
    var d;
    var maxd;
    var today = clearTime(new Date());
    for (i=0; i<colCnt; i++) {
        date = resourceDate(i);
        headCell = dayHeadCells.eq(i);
        if(resources[i].anwesenheit[date.getDay()-1] != null){
            var von = resources[i].anwesenheit[date.getDay()-1].von;
            var _von = von.substring(0, 5);
            var bis = resources[i].anwesenheit[date.getDay()-1].bis;
            var _bis = bis.substring(0, 5);
            headCell.html(resources[i].name + "<p style='font-weight: normal; font-size: 11px;'>" + _von + " - " + _bis + " Uhr</p>");
        } else {
            headCell.html(resources[i].name); 
        }  

        headCell.attr("id", resources[i].id);
        bodyCell = dayBodyCells.eq(i);
         if (+date == +today) {
            bodyCell.addClass(tm + '-state-highlight fc-today');
        }else{
            bodyCell.removeClass(tm + '-state-highlight fc-today');
        }
        setDayID(headCell.add(bodyCell), date);

    }
}
```

This shows the work time from each resource right unter the name of the resource.

Also I added a serverside function to the select function which checks if the resource is available. If yes, then the event will be created, else the event won't be created and I get an error message.

Now I can work with it. It's not exactly what I wanted, but it's nice to use now. It updates the times under the resource name on every day change so I have an overview when a resource is available and when it's not available.